# Cannot Retreive Boolean from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, boolean

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, but I am not able to figure out this issue.
I am trying to do achieve an if statement based on a boolean value in the Firebase database. I have tried various combinations, but my most recent attempt is below.

**When I run the app with the below code:**

- Nothing happens
- There is no error message
- The "likeButtonNotClicked" button displays (for both true and false conditions)

```
RetreiveLikeReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Main Wall Posts").child(postId).child("liked")

 private void UpdateLike() {

      if(RetreiveLikeReference.equals(true)){
          likeButtonClicked.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
          likeButtonNotClicked.setVisibility(GONE);
      } else {
          likeButtonClicked.setVisibility(GONE);
          likeButtonNotClicked.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

      }

    }
```

I also tried the code below and got the same result.

```
RetreiveLikeReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.exists()) {
                   snapshot.getValue();
                   if (snapshot.equals(true)){
                       likeButtonClicked.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                       likeButtonNotClicked.setVisibility(GONE);

                   } else {
                       likeButtonClicked.setVisibility(GONE);
                       likeButtonNotClicked.setVisibility(VISIBLE);


                   }


               } 
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

           }

       });
```

Comment: Did you try: `if (snapshot.getValue() == true){`

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, with that line of code, im getting the following error message: "Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Object', 'boolean'

Comment: `if ((Boolean.valueOf(snapshot.getValue())) == true){`

Comment: Omg that worked! Thank you so much. I have been stuck on this for days.

Comment: np :-) tbh I think `if (snapshot.getValue().equals(true)){` would also work, but its not as obvious what you are attempting to achieve with that code. You where pretty close :-)

Comment: You might even be able to do `if ((Boolean)snapshot.getValue())`.

Comment: @Blundell You can simplify to `if (Boolean.valueOf(snapshot.getValue())`. Comparing `== true` or `== false` is always redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the boolean value from your database using the `Boolean.valueOf()` method. You're not telling java the type of value that you are getting so java sets automatically the type of the value to `Object`.

You can fix it by telling to java that the value type is `Boolean` like this:

```
if ((Boolean.valueOf(snapshot.getValue()))) {/* You code here...*/}
```